Linearizing constraints involving max function
This is a follow up to the question
Linearizing a Max Function in the constraint - not working
Suppose I want to solve the following
$
\begin{aligned}
\min \quad & X\\
\text{s.t.}  \quad & \\
\quad & Z(i) = \max (Y(i,1),...,Y(i,n) ) \\
\quad &...
\end{aligned}
$
where $X$ is a positive discrete variable
and   $Y(i,j)$ are real positive variables
The model involves additional constraints.
Is it possible to solve this model without introducing binary variables?

How does $X$ relate to $Y(i,j)$ and $Z(i)$?

Hugh, ... This is not possible to explain without showing the whole model; this, unfortunately I cannot do. I can say, that X represents makespan and the Y(i,j) relate to quantities to be processed/produced. I just wander if it is possible to avoid the max function by somehow adding the Z(i)s to the objective, as indicated in the question I refer to.

Is it possible to get a smaller $X$ by relaxing the equality constraint to $Z(i) \ge \max()$?

How about splitting the max function and dividing the condition by segments?

@Xminer What do you mean?

@RobPratt Yes, I get a smaller X if I do the relaxation and the value of X I get is wrong. I need to impose Z(i) <= max() as well in order to get the correct optimal value. I should notice, that the vars Y(i,j) are bounded as 0 <= $Y(i,j)$ <= Y(i,j)^{max}.

Then your problem is not convex, and you need either binary variables or nonlinear constraints.

Or you can approximate by penalizing $Z(i)$ in the objective as described in @prubin's answer to the linked question: https://or.stackexchange.com/a/6038/500

@RobPratt Thank you Rob, I will try Rubin's approach. How would it be different if weren't possible to get a smaller X by relaxing the equality constraint to Z(i) => max()?

If relaxing to $Z(i)\ge\max()$ yields the same optimal objective value, then you can just solve the relaxation, which can be linearized via $Z(i)\ge Y(i,j)$.
